# ¿Permitir enviar formularios cada cierto tiempo? PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, formularios, timer

lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario solo pueda enviar el mensaje si ya  han pasado 10 segundos desde que envió el anterior, alguien me puede ayudar y explicar cómo se hace esto, gracias.

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])){ 
$sqll4 = ("SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE usuario = '".$user."' ORDER BY id DESC");
      $run14 = mysqli_query($db, $sqll4); 
      $row14 = mysqli_fetch_array($run14);
      $antade = $row['date'];

$date = date('h:i:s'); 
if ($date - $antdate >= strtotime('00:00:10')){ 
    $mensaje= $_POST['mensaje'];
     $sqll3 = ("INSERT INTO mensajes VALUES('', '$id','$user', '$mensaje', '$date')");
      mysqli_query($db, $sqll3); 
      $sqll5 = "UPDATE posts SET messages = messages + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'"; 
      mysqli_query($db, $sqll5);
       } }
```

Comment: Sin conocer tu proyecto, me da la sensación que lo que quieres hacer tendría más sentido que lo controlaras desde tu front con javascript. Por ejemplo, deshabilitar el botón de enviar durante 10 segundos o algo del estilo... Si realmente te interesa por algún motivo hacerlo desde el back, una opción puede ser que compruebes con un select hace cuanto mandó el último mensaje y, en caso de que la resta de la fecha actual con la del último mensaje sea menor a 10 segundos, dar algún tipo de error.

Comment: Hice esto pero no funciona:  `$antdate = date('h:i:s');
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
 $date = date('h:i:s');
 if ($date - $antdate >= strtotime('00:00:10')){
 $mensaje= $_POST['mensaje'];

$sqll3 = ("INSERT INTO mensajes VALUES('', '$id','$user', '$mensaje', '$date')");
mysqli_query($db, $sqll3);
$sqll5 = "UPDATE posts SET messages = messages + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysqli_query($db, $sqll5);
$antdate = $date;
}
}`

Comment: Esque $antdate deberia estar inicializado con la fecha del último mensaje que haya en la base de datos con el id del usuario que está mandando el mensaje. Ahora mismo $antdate está inicializado con la fecha actual

Comment: if(isset($_POST['send'])){ 
 $sqll4 = ("SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE usuario = '".$user."' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $run14 = mysqli_query($db, $sqll4); 
    $row14 = mysqli_fetch_array($run14);
    $antade = $row['date'];

 $date = date('h:i:s'); 
 if ($date - $antdate >= strtotime('00:00:10')){ 
  $mensaje= $_POST['mensaje'];
   $sqll3 = ("INSERT INTO mensajes VALUES('', '$id','$user', '$mensaje', '$date')");
    mysqli_query($db, $sqll3); 
    $sqll5 = "UPDATE posts SET messages = messages + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'"; 
    mysqli_query($db, $sqll5);
     } }

Comment: da error ese también

Comment: Por favor, borra los comentarios con el código y añade el código que estas probando a la pregunta. Si no, aparte de ser ilegible, estamos llenando esto de comentarios

Comment: Ya, ahora, ¿me puedes ayudar?por favor

Comment: Prueba a hacer esto:  if (strtotime($date) - strtotime($antdate) >= strtotime('00:00:10')){ ...}

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: date in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\chat.php on line 59
Line 59: `$antade = $row['date'];`
Notice: Undefined variable: antdate in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\chat.php on line 62
Line 62:  `if (strtotime($date) - strtotime($antdate) >= strtotime('00:00:10')){`

Comment: Es $antade, me he equivocado al escribir la variable... y es $row14, no $row...

Answer (score 2):

¿Por que lo haces con PHP? Si estas ya guardando los datos con MySQL utiliza sus ventajas.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'COUNT' 
FROM mensajes WHERE usuario = '".$user."' 
AND date > ( NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND )";

// Primero validamos que la consulta esté bien formada
if( !$result = mysqli_query( $db, $sql ) ) {
  die('La consulta tiene errores');
} else {
  // Sacamos el resultado
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );

  //Liberamos memoria ¡ESTO ES IMPORTANTE!
  mysqli_free_result( $result );

  // Hacemos una condición ternaria para saber si puede postear
  // Si count tiene 0, entonces puede postear, contrario deberá esperar
  $puede_postear = $row['COUNT'] == 0 ? true : false;


  if( $puede_postear ) {
   // Aquí el insert
  } else {
   // Aquí algo si aún no puede hacer un post
  }
}
```

Te evitas de estar parseando fechas en PHP, espero te sirva.

**OJO**
El código funciona siempre y cuando tu campo en DB `date` sea de tipo `DATETIME O TIME`

Comment: No da errores pero tampoco funciona, me permite comentar normalmente sin límite de 10 segundos (el "date" es de tipo time)

Comment: ¿Seguro que lo haces antes de los 10 segundos? Por qué no haces un par de pruebas con 30 segundos. Intenta depurarlo haciendo `echo $row['COUNT']` o algo por el estilo. No tengo el ambiente para depurarlo yo, pero creo que más adeacuación de parte tuya a que funcione al 100% lo que yo hice. De mi lado, funciona perfecto el SQL.

Comment: Siempre me muestra un valor de cero, o sea, lo que se ve en la consola es "0"